# Reading QR code crashes iOS(Objective C) application

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, avfoundation, barcode-scanner

I have created one React Native application for barcode/QRCode scanning functionality. I used third party barcode scanner library.I am able to scan barcode properly, but application getting crashed on QR code scan.Here is sample code:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)output didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray<__kindof AVMetadataObject *> *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
 for (AVMetadataObject *object in metadataObjects) {
  if ([object isKindOfClass:[AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject class]]) {
    if (_callback != nil) {
        _callback(@{
                    @"format": object.type,
                    @"content": [(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)object stringValue]
                    });
    }
}
```

}
}

it returns nil when I am trying scan QR code and application is getting crash on this line

```
[(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)object stringValue]
```

and getting exception error is

```
-[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
```

Comment: you're using react-native on this project?

Comment: `[(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)object stringValue]` can be nil. I guess that's the case? You should test it beforehand.